# How to get all id's from inserted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am insert bulk of records how to get all those Id's from inserted tables.

I want to use all those ids as forgein keys and insert into another table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudCustomers]
           ([LegalName]
           ,[EffectiveDate]
           ,[LawsonCustomerNumber]
           ,[ChangeReason]
           ,[ImportedRecord]
           ,[VersionID]
           ,[StatusID]
           ,[CreatedDate]
           ,[CreatedUserID]
           ,[LastModifiedDate]
           ,[LastModifiedUserID]
           ,[CustomerGroupID])
SELECT CustomerName
         ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
         , CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CustomerName) > 0 
            THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CustomerName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CustomerName),
            LEN(CustomerName)), ')', '') 
            ELSE 0 END
         ,''
         ,1
         ,1
         ,1
         ,GETDATE()
         ,'Import'
         ,GETDATE()
         ,'Import'
         ,NULL
FROM External_Blk_Itm_Contracts
WHERE TerminalName NOT IN (SELECT MBFTERMINALNAME FROM budterminals)
```

Comment: I assume these IDs are identity values? The best way to do that is using the OUTPUT clause. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... OUTPUT col_name INTO #temp_table SELECT ...`

Comment: how can do that in this query

Comment: Which column you need?

Comment: CustomerId column from budcustomers table

Comment: Look at the documentation I linked. It explains how this works quite clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)** clause:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (CustomerId <datatype> );

INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudCustomers]
           ([LegalName]
           ,[EffectiveDate]
           ,[LawsonCustomerNumber]
           ,[ChangeReason]
           ,[ImportedRecord]
           ,[VersionID]
           ,[StatusID]
           ,[CreatedDate]
           ,[CreatedUserID]
           ,[LastModifiedDate]
           ,[LastModifiedUserID]
           ,[CustomerGroupID])
OUTPUT inserted.CustomerId
INTO #temp
SELECT CustomerName
         ,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
         , CASE 
           WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CustomerName) > 0 
            THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CustomerName, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', CustomerName),
            LEN(CustomerName)), ')', '')  ELSE 0 END
         ,''
         ,1
         ,1
         ,1
         ,GETDATE()
         ,'Import'
         ,GETDATE()
         ,'Import'
         ,NULL
FROM External_Blk_Itm_Contracts
WHERE TerminalName NOT IN (SELECT MBFTERMINALNAME FROM budterminals)

SELECT *
FROM #temp;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Probably `inserted.CustomerId` I updated answer

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: What if i have 2 columns to be inserted into temp table

Comment: like customer id and customer name

Comment: @user1030181 No problem `CREATE TABLE #temp (CustomerId <datatype> , LegalName <datatype>); OUTPUT inserted.CustomerId, inserted.LegalName INTO #temp`

Comment: but What if i have another column in temp table like Terminal id but it is coming from another selected statement.. In that case how to fill that terminalid column in temp table

Comment: @user1030181 Sorry but I don't get your case. Consider asking new question with example to describe what you want to achieve. With OUTPUT statement you have access only to `inserted` values.